# flutter web reload asset data after build

Tags: javascript, flutter, browser-cache

I want to build a flutter web application, which reads local data on run. As far as I know, the flutter web is not supported file io, so I use Asset to read the data instead.

Here comes the problem: the asset file sometimes changes. I need to **reload** the asset file every time I run the web app. I found the asset data won't update until I use **Incognito mode** in chrome. That's mean the data cached in chrome somehow?

I don't know how asset data used in flutter and how the asset data cached in the browser.

### Here are the simple reproduce steps I want to do:

1. Create a flutter web application
2. Create a simple SQLite database and initialize it from `Flutter Asset`
3. Build and run it on local
4. Update the database somehow
5. Re-run the flutter app <- database data from Asset is not updated
6. If I use **Incognito mode**, the data is up to date correctly

I wonder the cache can be clear in Flutter or need to be done in Javascript.

Any suggestion and explanation are grateful!

Comment: You don't need to use incognito. You can disable cache in Chrome > devtools > Network tab > disable cache. However you might need to keep the devtools window open for the setting to persist.

Comment: @ambiguous58 Thanks for your advice. But I am not looking for a developed solution but a general release solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rootBundle`.`loadString` for loading of yaml files. Those method has a parameter which disallow caching.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/AssetBundle/loadString.html

Comment: `loadString` actually only works for text asset files (as I tried and the document description). Also, the `cache: false` only works with Incognito mode.